# Sorting products by discount percentage

Tags: php, database, sorting, laravel-8

I am trying to sort products by discount percentage in my laravel app.
I have two columns in my products table i.e. price, discount_price. How can I order order them so that products with higher discount shows up higher in order. I've tried following but it doesn't work

```
$products = DB::table('products')->get();
$sorted_products = $products->sortBy('price - discount_price');
```

Any pointers plz, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `select` method and `DB::raw` to add a RAW SQL component to the query. Assunming that discount is the discount in currency units we are interested in fetching all the fields (`*`) plus the calculated field `price - discount` which we will call `real_price`.

```php
$sorted_products = DB::table('product')
                       ->select(DB::raw("*, price - discount as real_price"))
                       ->orderBy("real_price")
                       ->get();
```

This will build the following SQL query and execute it:

```sql
SELECT *, price - discount as real_price FROM product ORDER BY real_price;
```

If the discount is as percentage you could:

```php
$sorted_products = DB::table('product')
                       ->select(DB::raw("*, price * discount as real_discount"))
                       ->orderBy("real_discount")
                       ->get();
```

Which would be ordered by higher discount value.